# AzureDevOps pipeline triggers other pipelines after change?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd, azure-pipelines-yaml

Is there an easy way how I can use an Azure DevOps pipeline, for example to build microservices (golang monorepo (after i tried single repos)) or my own libraries after a change, which then trigger another pipeline from another service that uses them?

For example the structure is like

```
|- Service1
  |--- pipeline1.yml
|- Service2
  |--- pipeline2.yml
|- libraries
  |--- libraries1
  |--- libraries2
  |--- pipelinelibraries.yml
```

So, pipeline1 and pipeline2 look almost the same. A few parameters are different and both still use a template. After changes to the services, only these individual pipelines are triggered.
e.g. (just small example, this  already works)

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
      - 'pathTO/service1/*'
parameters:
  - name: name
    ....

  - and so on

stages:
  - template: ../template.yml #e.g. build stage
    parameters:
      name: xxx
      ...
```

But if now one Service is using lib1, and there are changes at lib1, how can i run/build the Libs pipeline and after that the service using the librarie which had changes? Is this possible?
e.g.
(first get triggered and then try wit jobs to trigger other?)

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
      - 'libs/*'

jobs:
  - job: buildIt
    steps:
      - ...
```

I hope I was able to describe it clearly?

As you can already read above, my individual pipelines work and I tried to create another one for e.g. my libraries. I then tried to build the changed library (or all libraries) and then using a job to trigger the services that use the library in which something was changed. so that change can be attracted immediately. However, that didn't work. I also googled it because I thought it's definitely not something that only I want to do (which I still assume). But somehow I couldn't find anything that would have helped me.

Comment: Webhooks are a first thought. You can then do what you want to do everytime a specific pipeline has finished executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [the pipeline resource trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops).

It will allow you trigger the second pipeline on the completion first.

First pipeline

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
      - 'libs/*'

jobs:
  - job: buildIt
    steps:
      - ...
```

And the second pipeline:

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
      - 'pathTO/service1/*'
parameters:
  - name: name
    ....

  - and so on

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: lib # Name of the pipeline resource.
    source: lib-ci # The name of the pipeline referenced by this pipeline resource.
    project: FabrikamProject # Required only if the source pipeline is in another project
    trigger: true # Run thie pipeline when any run of lib-ci completes

stages:
  - template: ../template.yml #e.g. build stage
    parameters:
      name: xxx
      ...
```

Comment: Seems that it worked with a few adjustments. thanks a lot. I also found the correct Documentation part now.  Another option I found... but doesn't quite fit what needs to be done. You can simply enter the paths in service1 e.g. "trigger: paths: include:" and adding 'libs/*'. Then it will be executed every time there is a change.