# How to orchestrate stand-alone pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Lets say, I have 4 Azure DevOps YAML pipelines: A, B, C and D. A and B can run in parallel, C depends on A and B and pipeline D depends on C.

So the graph looks like this:

```
A <-.
     |-- C <- D 
B <-'
```

'Depends on' means, that the downstream pipeline downloads resources from the upstream pipeline, e.g.:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: A
      source: A
    - pipeline: B
      source: B
```

Those pipelines may run on different branches. They are currently modeled as stand-alone pipelines and not as stages because we need to run them individually.

E.g., I want to run pipeline C after a code change with the last pipeline artifacts of A and B without running them again.

Now, I can run all those pipelines manually without a problem. But in 95% of the case I just want to run all pipelines in the defined order.

So is it possible to write an orchestrating pipeline that fulfills two requirements:

- It runs all those pipelines in the order and with the dependencies I mentioned (e.g. C must only run after A and B is finished successfully) without recreating them in new pipelines (as in copying pipeline code or using templates)
- It allows to set the branch for all of them so that A, B, C, D would all run on the given branch

Alternatively, is there a better way to achieve my goals?

AFAIK, adding a pipeline trigger would not work as e.g. if A finishes earlier than B, C would already start to run. But C needs to wait until B is done. This could be achieved by stages but then I cannot individually run the stages with different source artifacts.

Thanks!

Comment: @jaw Maybe someone thought the question belonged on [DevOps.SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Didn't even know about that. But if it is discouraged to ask CI/CD topics here, then downvoting is probably not really helpful to let prevent that from happening in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve the dependencies with a condition of the pipeline stages with the and operator to confirm that both stages a and b are succeeded  like this:

```
trigger:
- main

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - script: echo "Building"

- stage: B
  jobs:
  - job: Test
    steps:
    - script: echo "Testing"
      
- stage: Deploy
  dependsOn: 
  - A
  - B
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.A.result, 'Succeeded'), eq(dependencies.B.result, 'Succeeded')) 
  jobs:
  - job: Deploy
    steps:
    - script: echo "Deploying"
```

and then trigger the pipeline which is required to be run after the source artifacts change like in this question:

[AzureDevOps pipeline triggers other pipelines after change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77430885/azuredevops-pipeline-triggers-other-pipelines-after-change)

Comment: As I explained, I know how to use stages to model dependecies. But what I want to do is executing a different pipeline. In your example triggering a pipeline in stage A, another in stage B and waiting until both finish before starting stage "Deploy". I also know about the pipeline trigger but it should not trigger when running it manually as also explained in my question.

Comment: if you see the condition as mentioned will solve the first issue that it will wait until both a and b finished then the second one will be triggered by source code change which may have the source artifact from the first pipeline so it resolve the other issue

Comment: So, I know how to build this with stage, also how to use conditions. But it still does not solve the problem explained above. There should also be no trigger on source code change.